# Facebook persistent token and "Keep me logged in" using Node.js, Express and Passport

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, facebook-access-token

I would like to know how (if possible) it is possible to get a persistent token from Facebook as the authentication from Passport only gives a short-time token (from what i read).
If this is possible, i would to know how to allow the user to be still logged in whenever he reconnects to my website.
here is my (yet not really consistent) code :

```
var passport = require('passport')
    , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

 passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
     clientID: "xxxxx",
     clientSecret: "xxxxxx",
     callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
 },
     function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
     {
         done(null, profile);
     }
 ));

app.get('/login', function(req, res)
{
    res.end('<a href="/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>')      ;
})

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    res.end('logged in !')      ;
})


app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['user_event'] }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login' }));


var server = app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Have you figured out a solution?